# How to debug "linked command failed"?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

I've started learning C++ over some other high-level languages and it starts driving me crazy.

When I compile a program like that:

```
 gcc $FILE_TO_COMPILE -o $OUTPUT -lstdc++
```

All it works. CLion comes with its own cmake, so it executes the following command which also works:

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build /Users/username/studies/cmake-build-debug --target simple_example -- -j 4
```

but when I compile like that:

```
  gcc -O2 -static -v $FILE_TO_COMPILE -o $OUTPUT
```

I get a lot of verbose output which ends up with:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

OK, from verbose I can understand that I haven't attached proper lib to compile, but I'd love to  debug which part of my code uses this lib. Here's a gist with the code to reproduce the problem:
https://gist.github.com/Dominos/226b651a508cb48ce7272f7dd3e447e2

Can anyone tell me what's the proper way to debug problems like this? I don't need an answer **what's the problem**, I'd prefer **how to find out** this.

Comment: At a guess I would say the problem is that you've used `gcc` to compile a C++ program. Try again with `g++`.

Comment: In this case I think this is just one of those things you have to know. gcc does not pass the correct options to the linker for a C++ program, g++ does.

Comment: Yeah, `g++` works just fine. I've just read that core difference between `gcc` and `g++` is that, that `g++` is meant for C++, while `gcc` for C. 
Okay, so I think I'll leave that and will read more about linkers - thanks!